# Statistics for quantitative finance

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for an advanced introduction to statistics. I am currently interviewing for hedge fund positions, and a solid base in statistics would be quite helpful. As a math major I have significant (graduate level) background in analysis and probability, but somehow statistics has always evaded my course schedule. An ideal book would include several proofs in the exposition and a multitude of computational exercises.

Comment: The book "Time Series Analysis" by Hamilton is the ultimate book you need for a quant role in a hedge fund company.

Comment: @Gordon I'll be using that in a class next semester!

Answer (score 7):

Tsay's Analysis of Financial Time Series should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

I think that "An Introduction to Statistical Learning: with Applications in R (Springer Texts in Statistics)" suggested by KarolisR could be useful but too much machine learning oriented. Moreover, such a book is for beginners.

As a thorough book (PhD level) on statistics, I suggest "Statistical Inference" by Casella and Berger.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this one:
[An Introduction to Statistical Learning: with Applications in R (Springer Texts in Statistics)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1461471370).
Or maybe take a stats course on coursera/edx

Answer (score 1):

[Advanced Algorithmic Trading](https://www.quantstart.com/advanced-algorithmic-trading-ebook),  Mike Halls-Moore.